# Accord.Net Statistics.Tools. Quartiles Method()

Tags: c#, matrix, vector, percentile, accord.net

I am currently looking for a way to compute the `5th percentile` of a `column vector` (i.e `N x 1` `matrix`) using `Tools. Quartiles Method (Double[,] ,DoubleRange[])`, and hope to get some assistance on this.

So far my problem comes from the argument of **Type** `DoubleRange[]` within the method, as I do not know how to *input* it properly. As an illustration of the piece of code used, please find below:

```
 double[,] PMat = Matrix.ToMatrix(dat); // dat being of Type DataTable...methods works
```

Given the ambigous `Tools` name between `Accord.Math.Tools` and `Accord.Statistics.Tools`

I've defined:

```
double[] Percentile = Accord.Statistics.Tools.Quartiles(PMat, xxxx) 
                    // all attempts using xxxx has mechanically lead to:
```

`Error: The best overloaded method match for Accord.Statistics.Tools.Quartiles(double[*,*], out AForge.DoubleRange[]) has some invalid arguments`

**EDIT**: My idea consists of calculating a `0.2 Quartile`, as a way around... So I had in mind something like `Accord.Statistics.Tools.Quartiles(PMat, 0.2)`

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to get percentiles and what I settled on was:

```
Accord.Statistics.Distributions.Univariate.EmpiricalDistribution
```

With that if your values are in a `double[]` then:

```
EmpiricalDistribution distribution = new EmpiricalDistribution(values);
distribution.InverseDistributionFunction(0.05);
```

Gives you the 5th percentile.

Note: the empirical distribution is non parametric.  The percentiles are simply the data values at the appropriate position once the data is sorted.  There is no interpolation or fitting as can be seen in the attached plot (which was produced with the above method):

[InverseDistributionFunction against percentile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9sd4.png)

Comment: Sure, however please note that your suggestion might only be relevant if you know (or make an assumption on) the `distribution` of the underlying data (i.e know the `CDF`...). My question was focusing more on cases like in a `Historical Simulation`, where one ends up with a distribution of `P/L`,   and is interested on the `5th percentile` of this data without assuming anything on the empirical distribution.

Comment: @dark.vador, I still think it does what you want.  I edited and added a picture.